# How can I generate editable PDF through web form

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, itext, acrobat

I created a web form using css,html and javascript. The web form has math back end. by choosing different options math will calculate accordingly and will result final code.

Now I need to generate editable PDF from that web form.

Cloud you please help me out with your suggestions.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try this, https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: The OP asked to do it with iText.

Comment: Are you using iText 5 or iText 7? The answer is different, depending on your iText version.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thank you for you reply. I'm not familiar with iText. I'm trying to figure out exact procedure for that in iText, unfortunately I'm against to the clock.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse If you explain bit more, It will be very helpful for me. Thank you

Comment: @ErrHunter Thank you for your reply.

Comment: iText 5 or iText 7? Java or C#?

Comment: I prefer java .

Comment: iText 5 or iText 7?

Comment: This question is off-topic on Stack Overflow. It is too broad, and it implicitly asks for a recommendation for a product. That is not allowed on Stack Overflow. You need to describe a specific technical problem, providing some code that allows Stack Overflow readers to reproduce that problem. You don't have a specific problem; you just say: "I need to create a form in PDF"; you don't provide any code that shows what you have tried so far; you just say: "Please show me how it's done." That's not what Stack Overflow is for.